# why ptrVec = new vector<const char*> compiles failed

Tags: c++, vector

What's wrong with below code? While it compiles with dev-c++, it complains:

> 18 E:\projects\pointer_test\main.cpp no match for 'operator=' in
>   'ptrVec = (((const std::allocator&)((const
>   std::allocator*)(&allocator()))),
>   (((std::vector >*)operator
>   new(12u)), (->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector with _Tp =
>   const char*, _Alloc = std::allocator,
>   )))'
>
> note d:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\vector.tcc:131 candidates are:
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = const char*, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator]
>
> 19 E:\projects\pointer_test\main.cpp base operand of `->' has
>   non-pointer type`std::vector
>
> 21 E:\projects\pointer_test\main.cpp could not convert `ptrVec' to`
>   bool'
>
> 23 E:\projects\pointer_test\main.cpp base operand of `->' has
>   non-pointer type`std::vector
>   24 E:\projects\pointer_test\main.cpp no match for 'operator=' in
>   'ptrVec = 0'
>
> note d:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\vector.tcc:131 candidates are:
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = const char*, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator]

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<const char*> ptrVec ; 
    ptrVec = new vector<const char*> ;
    ptrVec->push_back("Hello");

    if (ptrVec)
    {
           ptrVec->clear();
           ptrVec = NULL;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If the type of emelemts in a vector is pointer, how to do to avoid memory leak issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `vector<const char*> ptrVec;` is a vector of pointers, *not* a pointer to a vector. This means that allocating a vector object with `ptrVec = new vector<const char*>() ;` is incorrect. (Most likely, the compiler is complaining because of the missing parentheses.)

You have two choices to fix the problem:

1. Declare the vector as a pointer:

   ```
   vector<const char*>* ptrVec;
   ```
2. Clean up the code so that it works with a vector *object*:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       vector<const char*> ptrVec ; 
       ptrVec.push_back("Hello");
       ptrVec.clear();

       system("PAUSE");
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

Note that in option 1, you should move the `push_back()` call inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

vector isn't a pointer to a vector, it's a vector of pointers. Get rid of the line

```
ptrVec = new vector<const char*> ;
```

and change all the `->` into `.`, and it will work. Also, get rid of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If the char* is allocated on the heap, it needs to be manually released.
I suggest you write this.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  vector<string> vec;
  vector<string> *vecPtr = new vector<string>();
  vec.push_back("hello");
  vecPtr->push_back("world");

  if (vecPtr) {
    delete vecPtr;
    vecPtr = nullptr;
  }

  system("pause");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

vec is allocated on the stack, can auto release,
vecPtr is pointer, allocated on the heap, must manually released